# On click reveal an email address

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have the following code that allows me to reveal an email address on click.
The problem is that I want the **Show E-mail** to disappear when I click on it and just return the email address.

Can you please help?

Thanks!

```js
function SEmail() {
  var x = document.getElementById('email');
  if (x.style.display == 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="email">
  <?php _e('E-mail:', 'theme') ?>
  <span onclick="SEmail()"><a href="#">Show E-mail</a></span>
  <span id="email" style="display:none"><a href="mailto:<?php echo contact_email(); ?>">Email link</a></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Protip: One-character variable names will make you a lot of enemies. Give them semantic names for clarity.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: So what have you tried to hide the text? It's the exact same process you're using to show the email.

Comment: Instead of testing whether the email isn't visible, just go ahead and show it. The test is pointless. And in the same vein, just go ahead and turn the email link invisible, using the exact same mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another function to hide it onclick

try this

HTML:

```
<p class="email">
  <?php _e('E-mail:', 'theme') ?>
  <span onclick="SEmail()"><a href="#">Show E-mail</a></span>
  <span onclick="HideEmail()" id="email" style="display:none"><a href="mailto:<?php echo contact_email(); ?>">Email link</a></span>
</p>
```

JavaScript

```
function SEmail() {
  var x = document.getElementById('email');
  if (x.style.display == 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  } else  {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function HideEmail() {
  var x = document.getElementById('email');
  x.style.display = 'none';
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the below, by giving the **text** id to the placeholder text:

```
<script>
function SEmail() {
    var x = document.getElementById('email');
        x.style.display = 'block';
    var y = document.getElementById('text');
        y.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

```
<p class="email">
  <?php _e('E-mail:', 'theme') ?>
  <span id="text" onclick="SEmail()"><a href="#">Show E-mail</a></span>
  <span id="email" style="display:none"><a href="mailto:<?php echo contact_email(); ?>">Email link</a></span>
</p>
```

Thanks for help **@ChrisG** and **@isherwood**